# textarea placeholder does not work in IE10

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder

I'm setting `placeholder`s of `input` `text` and they works normally in `IE9+`.

```
<textarea style="some-style" name="some-name" id="some-id" class="some-class" 
 placeholder="awesome placeholder"></textarea>
```

This above does not work out.
I tried also to use a [plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder), but it does not change anything. Also tried to search through older questions but didn't find anything

**EDIT**

I noticed a strange behaviour: the content of the `textarea` on boot is the `text` of the `placeholder` and so not-empty, if I delete it then the `textarea` is empty and the `placeholder` works normally

Comment: isn't that how placeholders are supposed to work?

Comment: no because the first time it is a value, not a placeholder, I've to delete it by selecting it

Comment: Ok.. so if you typed something inside the textarea wouldn't you expect the placeholder to disappear?  Everything between the opening/closing tag is the content of the textarea

Comment: also what do you mean by first time it is a value?

Comment: If I type something inside the textarea, for the first time, it is typed "with" the placeholder. If I then delete all the text which is: the placeholder plus the things i typed, then the textarea is empty and the placeholder works out as well

Comment: It seems like something else in your code is setting the value attribute of the text area before it is shown.

Comment: This is your example code in it's simplest form. http://jsfiddle.net/cVrbH/ Works fine for me. Sounds like something else (maybe this other plugin you mentioned) is setting the value attribute to the text of the placeholder.

Comment: I solved overwriting the textarea value

Answer (score 1):

You can set a text for placeholder in title attribute and use this function with jQuery library

```
   $('textarea').focus(function() {
        if(this.title==this.value) {
        this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function(){
    if(this.value=='') {
        this.value = this.title;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's nothing 'inside' the textarea. No gap between the opening and closing tags. Also, I don't think the placeholder attribute works in IE9, but should in IE10.

```
<textarea style="some-style" name="some-name" id="some-id" class="some-class"  placeholder="awesome placeholder"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use for IE

```
var eMail = $('input').val();
$('input').click(function () {
    $(this).val('');
});
$('input').focusout(function () {

    if ($('input').val() != '') {
       //..
    } else {
        $(this).val(eMail);
    }
});
```

You can also use it with textarea

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll just go ahead and post my answer, even though this bug is old, because none of the others were suitable for me and the bug is still very much persistent.

```
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    // Check to see if the placeholder value equals the actual value
    if ($(this).attr('placeholder') == $(this).val()) {
      // If so, empty the actual value
      $(this).val("");
    }
  });
```

Basically it checks to see if any textarea element has a value that equals its placeholder, and if so it empties the value. It is a safe assumption that on page render no textarea element should have a value equalling its placeholder, so I think this is a solid fix.